# How many years will be deducted, if education in B.Com and experience as a graphic designer

Tags: visa, australia, india, pr

I have completed my bachelor of commerce degree in India, and I have 5 years of experience as a graphic designer. Now I plan to move Australia as a graphic designer, does the assessment authority reduce my experience for non-relevant education?